# Android Studio MacOS Big Sur Buttons Not Clickable

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, macos-big-sur

Recently after I've updated my mac os to latest version, Big Sur, i've ran into a problem in android studio.

Buttons and fields aren't clickable or editable. Even if they can be clicked there would be a really long long and annoying delay.

Do you guys know any fix for it?

Any help is really appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command in terminal and restart Android Studio

```
defaults write http://com.google.android.studio AppleWindowTabbingMode manual
```